# A service for checking compilability of C/C++ code by as many compilers as possible?

Tags: c++, c, web-services, compiler

Let's consider a scenario where you want to see how certain code behaves when compiled by variuos compilers. My specific example, I want to check how certain construct behaves when compiled by different versions of MS Visual Studio (let's say I am doing some update and want to make sure I didn't break something in older versions perhaps).

Currently, I would just basically install those on my machine, or check someone elses machine and get it running there. However this seems a bit chaotic. More systematic way would be to have some server set up with all of those (could be actually part of continuous integration/testing). Maybe that is something other people might want, so I was wondering if there is not already some service for this out there. Basically it would be something similar already exists for checking web in many different browsers, but for C/C++ compilers. And indeed I have found for example https://godbolt.org/, perhaps there are more and/or better services out there?

Few criteria (not requirements):

- It should support at least GCC & Visual Studio, but of course more is better
- More versions it support for given compiler, the better
- Ideally, it should allow one to inspect compilation errors/warnings
- More configuration possibilities, the better (perhaps being able to make basic preprocessor macros settings, being able to compile as C as well as C++, etc...)
- Being able to test given code on selected compilers at once would be nice (without going one by one)